# Is there a way to do multithreading with gedit in windows 7?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, multicore

I am new to threading (multicore programming). I was told that programming with parallel process threads can only be done on linux systems, and not windows? Is that true?

I have a Windows 7 system. My homework is the use pthreads to do matrix multiplication in C++. Is there any way for me to do it on my Windows 7?

Also, my teacher asked my to use gedit. How do I run codes in Gedit? I do not see a compile button, and do not know what I can do in place of the compilation command in linux?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get a Windows implementation of pthreads here: http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/  However, you should probably use the system that your instructor suggests, since that's going to be the system that your project will be run on for evaluations and grading. You should work out these problems/questions with your instructor, not the Internet at large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gedit is just a text editor , maybe your teacher use it in order to write code.

For implementing pthread you can use a IDE such like codeblocks , it's free.

open a new project , and in build option -> lincker setting add  : pthread , finally include in your project "pthread.h" then you can create , destroy .threads as you want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in Windows 7, Install a virtual machine and any ubuntu (Linux variant). Use the virtual machine to access ubuntu from windows7 itself. And then install gcc and gedit tools on your ubuntu. Write a code on gedit, save it and then from the command prompt run the following command to compile it:

```
gcc code.c -o code
```

code will be your executable.